# Undeclared namespace prefix "wsx" error accessing MS Dynamics CRM Online (2011) access from Java

Tags: java, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I've followed the walkthrough on MSDN

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602979.aspx
```

But hit this error each time (I've run thorough this a few times to make sure I'd not messed it up).

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.neethi.builders.converters.ConverterException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Undeclared namespace prefix "wsx"
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [42,50]
    at org.apache.neethi.builders.converters.StaxToDOMConverter.convert(StaxToDOMConverter.java:49)
    at org.apache.neethi.builders.converters.StaxToDOMConverter.convert(StaxToDOMConverter.java:38)
    at org.apache.neethi.builders.converters.ConverterRegistry.convert(ConverterRegistry.java:139)
    at org.apache.neethi.AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.invokeBuilder(AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.java:129)
    at org.apache.neethi.AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.build(AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.java:110)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.processOperationElement(PolicyBuilder.java:225)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.getAllOperator(PolicyBuilder.java:185)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.processOperationElement(PolicyBuilder.java:218)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.getExactlyOneOperator(PolicyBuilder.java:181)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.processOperationElement(PolicyBuilder.java:216)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.getPolicyOperator(PolicyBuilder.java:175)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.getPolicy(PolicyBuilder.java:114)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.getPolicy(PolicyBuilder.java:100)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyEngine.getPolicy(PolicyEngine.java:80)
    at java2crmpack.DiscoveryServiceStub.getPolicy(DiscoveryServiceStub.java:289)
    at java2crmpack.DiscoveryServiceStub.populateAxisService(DiscoveryServiceStub.java:57)
    at java2crmpack.DiscoveryServiceStub.<init>(DiscoveryServiceStub.java:96)
    at java2crmpack.DiscoveryServiceStub.<init>(DiscoveryServiceStub.java:85)
    at java2crmpack.Main.createDiscoveryServiceStub(Main.java:186)
    at java2crmpack.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Undeclared namespace prefix "wsx"
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [42,50]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.constructWfcException(StreamScanner.java:630)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwParseError(StreamScanner.java:467)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.NsInputElementStack.resolveAndValidateElement(NsInputElementStack.java:369)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleStartElem(BasicStreamReader.java:2947)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromTree(BasicStreamReader.java:2848)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1019)
    at org.apache.neethi.builders.converters.StaxToDOMConverter.readDocElements(StaxToDOMConverter.java:129)
    at org.apache.neethi.builders.converters.StaxToDOMConverter.convert(StaxToDOMConverter.java:44)
    ... 19 more
```

Has anyone come across this and managed to overcome it?

Ta.

Comment: have a look at [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dynamics-coe/archive/2013/09/21/integrating-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-online-with-java-and-other-non-net-clients.aspx)

Comment: I've tried editing "OrganizationServiceStub.java", as in the article, but alas I get the same error message.

Answer (score 1):

Replace all the occurrences of 'wsx:' in both, OrganizationServiceStub.java and DiscoveryServiceStub.java files.
Namespace is not necessary there since it is already known by other up-level usage.